# Nginx how to run shell script on page load via lua module os execute and then serve directory listing?

Tags: nginx, bash, rewrite, lua

So I have a bash script that I want to execute/run on each "page load" of url so that it will modify (creating symlinks) to a `/public/html/`  folder that I want the server to then serve.

The problem is I figured out how to do one or the other not both.

I can show the directory with nginx root `/public/html/`  etc.
or I can run the script by having instead of root `/public/html/` having:

`content_by_lua("/myscript.sh")';`

But if I use content by lua, the script does run and create what I need inside `/public/html` but Nginx then just shows a blank screen. I want a way to then have nginx actually show the directory listing of `/public/html` after it runs the `myscript.sh` using `content_by_lua`.

I just started using nginx because of this task and am clueless how to do this, I did search around but its not an easy question to phrase for google or here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I just figured it out? I added ngx.redirect("/"); 
So I have a / with location /public/html/ in my nginx.conf and also a:

```
    location /lua {
    default_type text/plain;
    content_by_lua '
    os.execute("/myscript.sh")
    return ngx.redirect("/")';
```

I would have preferred to just one 'location' instead of using redirect like that but at least I have something that seems to work. Improvements are welcome.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  Your shell script never returned any content, hence the blank page.  Send like a goofy way to do it ( run the script when the content changes, not on a user request) but I'm sure you're way beyond this now anyway.  Cool example of inline Lua though!